# Why is this PHP code not working for date 2012,02,26?

Tags: php

I am using this, but it's not working for date `2012,02,26`:

```
$theDate = "2012,02,26";
$timeStamp = StrToTime($theDate);
$in6days = StrToTime('+6 days', $timeStamp);
$newdate = date("{$theDate}", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($in6days))); 

echo "$newdate";

showing 2012,02,32
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 2012,02,26 is a valid format that strtotime() will accept. Valid date formats are listed here: [PHP: Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: So that means you can fix it by replacing the ',' with '-'. See str_replace: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: Yes - but it is up to the OP what kind of format he wants to go for.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the `strToTime` function works or not , try:

```
echo $timeStamp;
```

If  you get `false` then you should use another data format as christophmccann recommended,
for instance:

```
$theData = "02/16/2012"; //or the next one
$theData = "30-6-2008";
```

Comment: i have this js

year = 2012; month = 03; day = 30;hour= 16; min= 0; sec= 0;main_titel=...

i need with php add 6 days

Comment: there's no problem , after getting the timestamp , do your calculation and use `date()` to convert the timestamp to your deisered pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should be working *internally* with widely used date formats - either unix timestamp or RFC 2822 if you have good reason to. Use `date()` to reformat your date according to your own display requirements if you wish (see [php.net/date](http://php.net/date)).

So, you can show today in your preferred date format using `echo date('Y,m,d');`